# Can't get my data from a store to load in the view

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm new to Sencha Touch2 and I'm trying to start off my app by loading arbitrary data from a simple store before I go on to using a proxy. My view shows but the data is not populating. I've seen this question but nothing that has helped me solve. Any help and patience is appreciated. Thanks in adavance!

**My Model**

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       config: {
             fields: [
                {name: 't', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'distr', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'group', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'site', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'status', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'actuve', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'assigned', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'state', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'schedule', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'finished', type: 'string'} ],
       }
       });
```

**My View**

```
var distrStore = Ext.create('SenchaFirstApp.store.DistributorStore');
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.view.DistributorView', {
           extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
           requires: [distrStore, 'Ext.data.Store', 'Ext.dataview.List'],
           model: 'SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors',
           xtype: 'mainlist',
           fullscreen: true,

       config:
       {
           fullscreen: true,
           layout: 'fit',
           border: 5,
           title: 'Distributors',
           html: 'My datalist',
           autoLoad: true,

           items:{
               title: 'Setup',
               xtype:'list',
               store: distrStore,
               fields: [
                  {
                      text: 'T',
                      width: 1,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 't'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'Distributor',
                      width: 50,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 'distr'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'Group',
                      width: 20,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 'group'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'Site Name',
                      width: 20,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 't'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'Status',
                      width: 5,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 'status'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'Active',
                      width: 5,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 'active'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'State',
                      width: 2,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 'state'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'Scheduled',
                      width: 10,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 'schedule'
                  },
                  {
                      text: 'Finished',
                      width: 10,
                      sortable: false,
                      hideable: false,
                      dataIndex: 'finished'
                  }
            ]
                  }

       }  
});
```

> distrStore.load();

**My Store**

```
Ext.define('SenchaFirstApp.store.DistributorStore', {
                        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
                        requires: ['SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors', 'Ext.dataview.DataView'],

                        config: {
                        //  xtype: 'distrlist',
                            storeId: 'mainlist',
                        model: 'SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors',
                        autoLoad: true,
                        data: [
                               {t: 'S', distr: 'Smart Systems', site: 'Smart Temps', status: "done", active: 'Yes', assigned: 'Me', state: 'IN',                                                                        schedule: 'today', finished: 'today'},
                               {t: 'I', distr: 'People', site: 'This One', status: "done", active: 'Yes', assigned: 'You', state: 'NC', schedule:                                                   'yesterday', finished: 'tomorrow'}
                              ]}});
```

**app.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.application({
    name: 'SenchaFirstApp',
    stores: ['DistributorStore'],
    models: ['Distributors'],
    views: ['DistributorView'],
    requires: ['SenchaFirstApp.view.DistributorView', 'Ext.dataview.DataView', 'SenchaFirstApp.model.Distributors', 'SenchaFirstApp.store.DistributorStore',    'Ext.dataview.List'],

launch: function() {    
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator');
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SenchaFirstApp.view.DistributorView'));
    }
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create an instance of your store:

```
var distrStore = Ext.create('SenchaFirstApp.store.DistributorStore');
```

Because when you define your store in your application...

```
Ext.application({
    stores: ['DistributorStore'],
    ...
});
```

...it is automatically created for you. To get a reference of your store in your view, simply use a string with the name:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    store: 'DistributorStore',
    ...
}
```

**Other notes**

- You also do not need to load it using `.load()` because you have set `autoLoad` to true in your store config.
- Your view should extend `Ext.Container`, not `Ext.dataview.DataView`. DataView is used to show data (basically an abstract `Ext.List`. Because you have a list as an item, you can just put it inside a container.
- You have set `fullscreen: true` on the class as well as in the config. You only need to put it inside the config - but it isn't really neccessary because you are creating and inserting your view into `Ext.Viewport` (in your `app.js`) which is already fullscreen.
- You do not need `fields` config inside your list. You should use a `itemTpl` to create the template for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It helped clear some things up for me. However, I made all of the suggested changes and my data still doesn't show and the lines that separate the two rows are now gone. Are you able to see what I am still missing. Thanks again. I appreciate the help. I haven't been able to find one solid example of the way I'm doing it so I've meshed together different examples which probably isn't good :/

Comment: I used my storeId ('mainlist') to reference my store within my view and I got my separator lines back and have no errors but still no data.

Comment: Finally! I had changed my config layout to 'vbox' for some reason, I didn't realize I had done that. Once I changed it back to 'fit'. it is working. Now I have some serious formatting issues but I now have data to work with. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Good job! If you ever run into a similar problem in the future; make sure you check the element inspector in Chrome/Safari. There you can see if the list/data/component actually exists. If it does, then you know it is a layout issue. :)